# too many redirects error (.htaccess help needed)

Tags: .htaccess

lets say there is a file **about.php** abc.com.
In `.htaccess` file i have `RewriteRule  ^about_us/?$   about.php` .
when `abc.com/about_us` is entered in url, about.php will be  loaded inernally.
`abc.com/about.php` can also be loaded from url.

i need `abc.com/about_us` to be working. when some one types `abc.com/about.php` in url it should be 301 redirected o `abc.com/about_us`.

I tried with `Redirect 301 /about.php http://www.abc.com/about_us` but it did'nt work.

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going through your .htaccess file, you'll want to go through PHP for this.

An example for the index page would be:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/index.php') header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/");
```

and for the about page that you've specifically requested:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/about.php') header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/about_us");
```

These should go near the top of the PHP file, below any session management.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i need to do 301 redirect. Need to avoid duplicate content for seo.